# Json Encode working in one server and on another giving error undefined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, dropzone.js

I have very basic file upload system using PHP and Dropzone. Upload PHP file is like below

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
    // define absolute folder path
    $brand = $_POST['brand'];
    $reference = $_POST['reference'];

    $dest_folder = 'images/'.$brand.'/';
    $url = 'https://www.example.com/testupload/';
 
if(!empty($_FILES)) {

    if(!file_exists($dest_folder) && !is_dir($dest_folder)) mkdir($dest_folder);

    foreach($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] as $key => $value) {
        
        $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'][$key],PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
        
       
        if(file_exists($dest_folder) && !is_dir($dest_folder)){
             continue;
        }else{
            mkdir($dest_folder);
        } 
        
        $imgName =  $brand."-".$reference.'-picture'.$key.'.'.$ext;
        
        $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $targetFile =  $dest_folder.$imgName;
        move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
    }
    
    
         $dir = $dest_folder;
        $data = scandir($dir);
        $arr = [];
        
        
        foreach($data as $key=>$dataVal)
        {
            if($dataVal!='.' && $dataVal!='..'){
                
                 
                   $arr[] = $url.$dir.$dataVal; 
               
              
           }
        }
        
         $imgstring = implode(",",$arr);
        
    /**
     *  Response 
     *  return json response to the dropzone
     *  @var data array
     */
    $data = [
        "file" =>$brand,
        "dropzone" => $_POST["dropzone"],
        "img"=>$imgstring
    ];
    
    file_put_contents('abc.txt',$data);
    
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($data);
    exit();

}
```

and My DropZone js is like below

```
// disable autodiscover
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;


 
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#dropzone", {
    url: "upload.php",
    method: "POST",
    paramName: "file",
    autoProcessQueue : false,
    acceptedFiles: "image/*",
    maxFiles: 5,
    maxFilesize: 2, // MB
    uploadMultiple: true,
    parallelUploads: 100, // use it with uploadMultiple
    createImageThumbnails: true,
    thumbnailWidth: 120,
    thumbnailHeight: 120,
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    timeout: 180000,
    dictRemoveFileConfirmation: "Are you Sure?", // ask before removing file
    // Language Strings
    dictFileTooBig: "File is to big ({{filesize}}mb). Max allowed file size is {{maxFilesize}}mb",
    dictInvalidFileType: "Invalid File Type",
    dictCancelUpload: "Cancel",
    dictRemoveFile: "Remove",
    dictMaxFilesExceeded: "Only {{maxFiles}} files are allowed",
    dictDefaultMessage: "Drop files here to upload",
});

myDropzone.on("addedfile", function(file) {
    
    console.log(file);
});

myDropzone.on("removedfile", function(file) {
    // console.log(file);
});

// Add mmore data to send along with the file as POST data. (optional)
myDropzone.on("sending", function(file, xhr, formData) {
    formData.append("dropzone", "1"); // $_POST["dropzone"]
});

myDropzone.on("error", function(file, response) {
    console.log(response);
});




/**
 *  Add existing images to the dropzone
 *  @var images
 *
 */


 

    $("body").on("submit","#dropzone-form",function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
         
           var brand      =    $('body .brand').val();
                var reference   =  $("body .reference").val();
                
                if(brand=='' || reference==''){
                    alert('Please check your Input');
                    return false;
                }
         
         myDropzone.on("sending", function(file, xhr, formData){
                var brand      =    $('body .brand').val();
                var reference   =  $("body .reference").val();
                formData.append("brand", brand);
                formData.append("reference", reference);
            }),
        
           
         myDropzone.processQueue();
    });
    
    
    myDropzone.on("success", function(file,response) {

        console.log(response.img);
        $('#imgResponse').html(response.img);
    });
```

I have checked that

```
myDropzone.on("success", function(file,response) {

        console.log(response.img);
        $('#imgResponse').html(response.img);
    });
```

in above function I am able to run alert, so success event working but

```
console.log(response.img);
```

is not working.
Its working fine but just response is not getting properly and so its giving undefined message in console. Same code working fine in one server and another I am getting this error.
I have also checked that json module is enabled in server and tested using sample code for encode and decode. I have also checked that showing enabled in phpinfo(). I am not getting idea why its not working in this server. Let me know if someone can help me for solve the puzzle.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please comment out 2 below lines from the PHP script.

1. `file_put_contents('abc.txt',$data);`
2. `header('Content-type: application/json');`

And replace `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to `error_reporting(0);`
It will turn off the warning message from the server response.

Comment: Yeah! That was the issue, Its fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your file is being received on both server. Look like on the server with error your file is not uploading this is why you are getting empty response

Comment: Both files or on same server. I am saying that this all code works in one server without any error however its not working in another server. I am not sending files on different server. Thanks!

Comment: @RiyaShah you need to make sure that file you are uploading are coming to the server. You have a condition int the code that if no file is received there will be no response and on client end `response.img` would be `undefined`.  Just print_r $_FILES on the server which is working and server which is not working.

Comment: Files getting uploaded and there no any error in it. I have tested it, Even I hardcode img in $data, its still not working!

Comment: In this case you may need to provide more information. Can you share the response of both request?